# Verify binary search tree with duplicate keys

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search-tree

Given a binary tree with integers as its keys I need to test whether it is a correct binary search tree. Duplicate integers allowed. Smaller elements are to the left, bigger elements are to the right, and duplicates are always to the right

```
import sys, threading
def IsBinarySearchTree(tree):
  # Implement correct algorithm here
  min = -sys.maxsize
  max = sys.maxsize

  def is_bst_until(idx_node,maxi,mini, is_left = False):
    if idx_node == -1:
      return True

    node = tree[idx_node]
    key = node[0]
    idx_left = node[1]
    idx_right = node[2]    

    if (key>maxi) or (key<mini):
      return False

    if is_left:
      if (key==mini):
        return False

    return (is_bst_until(idx_right, maxi, key)) and (is_bst_until(idx_left, key-1, mini, is_left=True))

  if len(tree) == 0:
      return True
  return is_bst_until(0, max, min)


def main():
  nodes = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
  tree = []
  for i in range(nodes):
    tree.append(list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().strip().split())))
  if IsBinarySearchTree(tree):
    print("CORRECT")
  else:
    print("INCORRECT")

threading.Thread(target=main).start()
```

Input Format. The first line contains the number of vertices n. The vertices of the tree are numbered from 0 to n−1. Vertex 0 is the root. The next n lines contain information about vertices 0, 1, ...,  − 1 in order. Each of these lines contains three integers key, left and right

Output Format. If the given binary tree is a correct binary search tree, output one word “CORRECT”. Otherwise, output one word “INCORRECT”.

Examples:

```
3
2 1 2
2 -1 -1
3 -1 -1
#Incorrect

5
1 -1 1
2 -1 2
3 -1 3
4 -1 4
5 -1 -1
#Correct
```

I'm solving this task on one programming contest. And I failed to meet all test cases. Seems that I was mistaken somewhere. However I couldn't find the test case that is being incorrectly labeled.

I'll appreciate if you suggest me an my mistake

Comment: Can you edit the code to a runnable version?

Comment: @Chameera what problems do you have?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 41, in <module>
    threading.Thread(target=main).start()
NameError: name 'threading' is not defined

Comment: ok, edited. you need to import method `threading`, as well as `sys`

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys, threading
def IsBinarySearchTree(tree):
  # Implement correct algorithm here
  def is_bst_until(idx_node):
    if idx_node == -1:
      return True

    node = tree[idx_node]
    key = node[0]
    idx_left = node[1]
    idx_right = node[2]    

    if(idx_left != -1 and key <= tree[idx_left][0]):
        return False;

    if(idx_right != -1 and key > tree[idx_right][0]):
        return False;


    return (is_bst_until(idx_right)) and (is_bst_until(idx_left))

  if len(tree) == 0:
      return True
  return is_bst_until(0)


def main():
  nodes = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
  tree = []
  for i in range(nodes):
    tree.append(list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().strip().split())))
  if IsBinarySearchTree(tree):
    print("CORRECT")
  else:
    print("INCORRECT")

threading.Thread(target=main).start()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I guess your code doesn't cover the whole cases too. Try this input [[4,1,2], [2,3,4], [6,5,6], [1,-1,-1,], [3,-1,-1], [4,-1,-1], [7,-1,-1]]
As you see, the key of the left child of the node with key 6 is equal to the root, which is incorrect according to condition : `Duplicate integers allowed. Smaller elements are to the left, bigger elements are to the right, and duplicates are always to the right`

Comment: Maybe you can try inorder traversal and check whether it's increesting.